# How to extract source codes related to a certain functions in OPENCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am now using a very limited number of functions ( cv::Canny and cv::blur) in OPENCV, I do not want to use OPENCV library statically or dynamically as the library is big. Instead I want to just include all the source codes related to the functions that I will use (  cv::Canny and cv::blur). So here is my question:

1) is it feasible? I understand that functions in OPENCV are closely tied with each other.

2) If it is feasible, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you create/capture/get your image data? Do you want to still use cv::Mat datatypes or do you want to remove that from the canny/blur functions and work on the data arrays directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do, the same way you would include source files for any project.

Download the source, include the libraries header files.

1. You will need to watch for license issues
2. You might have dependancy issues depending on what includes you are using and you will need to build your own libraries.

You will need to watch for license issues.

This isn't really the correct way to do it though.

OpenCV library isn't actually that big, and it comes as a set of lots of small .dlls that can be included only when needed. For instance if you are only using the imgproc library you only need core and imgproc.